# Using Lambda as an Argument for an If Statement

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, extension-methods

Syntactically this is incorrect, but is there any way I can do something else using similar logic?

```
        if (Roster_Enrollment.Where(x => x.EID.Equals(EID_TextBox.Text)))
        {
            Message_TextBlock.Text = "EID already exists.";
        }
        else
        {
         ...
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `Any` method to find out if any of the items in the collection satisfies the condition:

```
if (Roster_Enrollment.Any(x => x.EID.Equals(EID_TextBox.Text)))
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error that states `SQLiteException was unhandled by user code.` I'll update the original question to provide more of the code I'm working with.

Comment: Nevermind, I just forgot to perform a type casting is all. Thanks for your help!